# Bash array as arguments to kafka-topics

Tags: linux, bash, apache-kafka

I have been struggling for a while with an init script to create Kafka topics. As some parameters need to be passed based on a condition, I researched and found that an bash array needs to be built. On the other hand, seems that `kafka-topics.sh` is unable to handle these. Following script (with Kafka prior to 2.5):

```
#!/bin/bash

args=("--if-not-exists"
  "--create"
  "--zookeeper localhost:2181"
  "--replication-factor 1"
  "--partitions 1"
  "--config retention.ms=-1"
  "--topic test"
)

/usr/local/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh "${args[@]}"
```

gives an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" joptsimple.UnrecognizedOptionException: zookeeper localhost:2181 is not a recognized option
    at joptsimple.OptionException.unrecognizedOption(OptionException.java:108)
    at joptsimple.OptionParser.handleLongOptionToken(OptionParser.java:510)
    at joptsimple.OptionParserState$2.handleArgument(OptionParserState.java:56)
    at joptsimple.OptionParser.parse(OptionParser.java:396)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$TopicCommandOptions.<init>(TopicCommand.scala:576)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:49)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
```

but this obviously works:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --if-not-exists --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --config retention.ms=-1 --topic test
```

Considering `kafka-topics.sh` is a bash script itself and runs a command:

```
exec $(dirname $0)/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.admin.TopicCommand "$@"
```

if I create a similar script using echo and pass the parameters as described in the first snippet, this works well:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec echo "$@"
```

Is there a way to properly pass parameters as an array to `kafka-topics.sh`?

Comment: does `/usr/local/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh ${args[@]}` work?

Comment: You have incorrect quoting when you create the array. `--zookeeper localhost:2181` should be two separate arguments rather than a single argument with a space in the middle. Same for `--replication-factor 1` And the others. As a general rule, use the same quoting to create the array that you’d use to pass the arguments directly — in this case, that means that no quoting is needed when you create the array. (But you should still use double-quotes when you *use* the array.)

Comment: Yes, quoting was the case! Thanks!

Comment: `zookeeper` is deprecated as an argument since around 2.3, I think